# Program crashes when inputs are high values

Tags: c++, if-statement, crash, while-loop

My code works when the values are small e.g. [a = 1, gos = 0.5, N = 1] & [a = 1, gos = 0.2 , N = 2].

However, it crashes when bigger values are entered. e.g.[a = 10, gos = 0.01, N = 18] & [a=50, gos=0.01, N=64].

How can I fix it?

Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
double num_trunks(double A, double B, int N);
double num_trunk_checker(double B, double gos, int N, double A);

double num_trunks(double A, double B, int N)
{
   double gos_prev = 1;
   double gos;
   int k = 1;
   while (k != (N+1))
   {
       gos = (A*gos_prev)/(k+(gos_prev)*A);
       gos_prev = gos;
       k++;    
   };
   num_trunk_checker(B,gos,N,A);
}

double num_trunk_checker(double B, double gos, int N, double A)
{
    if (B != gos)
    {
       N = N + 1;
       num_trunks(A,B,N);
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "Number of trunks: " << N << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   double A, gos;
   int N = 1;
   cout << "A: ";
   cin >> A;
   cout << "gos: ";
   cin >> gos;
   num_trunks(A,gos,N);

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What line does your debugger point to?

Comment: The program stops working after execution.

Comment: I'd guess you have a stack overflow through too much recursion

Comment: The program has no error. It just stops working when I enter high input values.

Comment: you are comparing 2 doubles  {if (B != gos)} , you should allow a small range of difference

Comment: But it works for lower values. How can I fix it?

Comment: At a glance, you have two functions calling each other, and the only way out involves an inequality test on doubles (`if (B != gos)`). I'm mildly surprised it ever works.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Your code is a little unusual in that `num_trunks` and `num_trunk_checker` have the `double` type identifier, but neither of them return anything. Are you familiar with the concept of returning a value from a function?

Comment: It's supposed to compute for N given a & gos.

Comment: Afungus -- If you have a question, please put it in your post.

Comment: Could you explain what real-life problem the function is supposed to solve? What do A, B, gos, and N represent?

Comment: It's a telecommunications problem for telephone lines.

Comment: Can you succinctly describe the telecommunications problem? Or is it too complex?

Comment: Sorry I can't explain it in much detail because of the complexity. Basically, this is a traffic problem and it solves for the amount of trunks needed for a system

Answer (score 2):

In `num_trunks(A, B, N)`, you calculate a `gos` value, and then call `num_trunk_checker(B, gos, N, A)`. But in `num_trunk_checker`, if `B` does not match `gos`, you turn around and call `num_trunks(A, B, N+1)`. So the only thing that changed is a larger `N`, and you get infinite recursion if `gos` never equals `B`.

```
num_trunks(A, B, N)
    calculuate gos (which has to be less than 1)
    num_trunk_checker(B, gos, N, A)

num_trunk_checker(B, gos, N, A)
    if (B != gos) num_trunks(A, B, N+1)
```

It is possible for `gos` to step over the value of `B`, so you never get equality.

Perhaps what you meant was:

```
    if (gos > B) //...
```

Comment: I changed that line into if (abs(B-gos)>0.0001) but it still crashes.

Comment: @Afungus: You probably want `fabs` from `<cmath>`, but that wasn't my suggestion. But yes, if you want to test fro equality, that is how it is usually done. My suggestion is `if (gos > B)`.

Answer (score 1):

you should read the FAQ about floating point comparisons

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html

then try sth like

```
if (fabs(B-gos)<1.e-6)
```

in num_trunk_checker function

Answer (score 0):

Without more information (what crashes? How long does it take?) it is impossible to solve your problem perfectly.  But some reasonable guesses can be made.

Floating point comparisons are not completely accurate and are usually done by subtracting the two values and comparing against a small value (called epsilon).  It might be better, when checking (B != gos), to do something like (B - gos < .00001).  Without this, the computation may not terminate; and if it did not, the recursion would continue indefinitely, until the stack overflowed and the program crashed.

Another possibility (I am not running the program to see what happens myself) is that with larger values, the multiplication causes them to overflow (to exceed the maximum possible value that can be represented in a double), causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: or better sth like fabs(B-gos)<1.e-6